# how to evaluate a js function return value

Tags: javascript, lua, cgilua

I have a proejct in which I use HTML/JS and Lua I want to evaluate the return value of a simple function, and honestly I don't get how to do it, here is a code snap  :

```
.......................................

<% if channel == nil  then %>   
<form name = "f1">
    <input type = "radio" Name = "r1" Value = "Input" onClick="GetSelectedItem(this)">Input
    <input type = "radio" Name = "r1" Value = "Output" onClick ="GetSelectedItem(this)">Output
    <input type = "radio" Name = "r1" Value = "Virtual" onClick ="GetSelectedItem(this)">Virtual
</form>

<div id="output"></div>     //  how can I  use this value in lua????
    <% end %>
...................................
<script> 
var output = document.getElementById('output');

function GetSelectedItem(el) {
    output.innerHTML = el.value;
}
</script>
```

**UPDATE **

since there is no way to tell lua which button was select , is it possible to evaluate the return value in HTML ?

```
if ( value == 1 ) then 
<% lua code for the 1. case %> 
if ( value == 2) then
```

and so on 
I write  C code because I don't how to do it in HTML/js 
is this way possible ? thanks again for the help!

Comment: what problem are you getting?

Comment: I know the way from Lua to HTML but not backway from HTML to Lua, I want to evaluate the return value in a lua script in html

Comment: What setup is this? to run Lua in the browser?

Comment: @rpattiso I don't understand your question :/

Comment: I don't understand how Lua is mixing with javascript and HTML, or what it is I'm seeing.

Comment: the code  <% write between those %> is lua code , the rest is HTML, I'm using Lua tale to the Hardware  I know how to display or use the Lua result in HTML/js but now I need this value of this js function in the Lua part of the code

Comment: @rpattiso do you any hint, I'll be thankful

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68739/discussion-between-rpattiso-and-engine).

Comment: The Lua template runs on the server and creates some HTML that is sent to the client. The Javascript code is then ran on the client, which has absolutely no knowledge of the Lua code used to generate the HTML. There is no way to communicate with the Lua template after it's been executed and sent to the client (but look into AJAX).

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo  & rpattiso I've updated the question